# Fine tuning a model - base_model Dropout in inference or training mode?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

In the TensorFlow documentation it is highlighted that it is important during fine tuning to set the base_model to ’inference mode’ setting the parameter `training = False` when calling the `base_model`. The reason to do so is because of the `tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization` layers, that should be executed in inference mode during fine tuning.
[TensorFlow documentation on Fine Tuning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning#fine_tuning)

But setting the `base_model` to inference mode will also affect the `tf.keras.layers.Dropout` in the `base_model` as these will then also run in inference mode and will not apply any dropout at all.

What is useful for getting meaningful results when fine tuning a model?

Running the dropout layers in the `base_model` in inference mode (no dropout at all) or running them in training mode applying the dropout as defined in the `base_model`?

Comment: What you can do is adjust the "training" parameter individually depending on the layer (Dropout or BN). Regarding your question about what is useful in fine-tuning a model to get meaningful results, I think this really depends on your use case and your data set and therefore requires a bit of trial and error, but that is just a subjective opinion.

Comment: @AloneTogether How can the parameter `training=False/True` be set separat per layer within an existing basemodel?

Comment: I was thinking of this part of docs regarding BN: "[...] However, in the case of the BatchNormalization layer, setting trainable = False on the layer means that the layer will be subsequently run in inference mode (meaning that it will use the moving mean and the moving variance to normalize the current batch, rather than using the mean and variance of the current batch)." https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization

Comment: @AloneTogether Ok, so setting `training=True` while setting `trainable=False`. As far as I remember from checking the source code, `trainable=False` in case of BN will overwrite the `training` value. But as is stated in the docs, the model would will run in training mode wwithout setting `training=False` explicitly.

Comment: Yeah exactly :) but I haven't tested it.. So if you try it out lemme know.

Comment: @AloneTogether I saw from the source code that on calling the layers the `training` parameter gets passed. Do you know if it can be set not global on a model when fine tunings, but per layer?